# Botão no action bar para abrir navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Bom, estou fazendo uma aplicação que usa o navigation drawer. A partir do android 5.1 o botão `"hamburguer"` no action bar funciona, e ao clicar nele a gaveta do navigation drawer abre.
Mas testei agora no celular com android 4.2 e no emulador com o mesmo android, e em nenhum dos dois aceita o click pra abrir a gaveta. Só abre deslizando. Pra versões mais antigas precisa implementar algum método?

```
public class MenuPrincipal extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ImageView img_Principal;
    DocumentView documentView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_principal);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_principal, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_carteira_profissional) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CarteiraProfissional.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_autenticar_carteira) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AutenticarCarteiraProfissional.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_processo_em_andamento) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Processo_em_Andamento.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_financeiro) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Financeiro.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_denuncia) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Denuncia.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_pessoa_fisica) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SolicitarInscricaoPessoaFisica.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_beneficios) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
    }
}
```

Lembrando que do android 5.1 pra cima tá funcionando o click no action bar, no 4 que não tá.

Comment: Insira na sua pergunta a parte mais relevante do seu código, a que você esta usando para criar o navigation drawer.